# iTunes visualiser always fullscreen

Tags: itunes, macos, fullscreen

Since upgrading to Yosemite this morning, the iTunes visualiser runs in fullscreen and I can't get it back to windowed mode. The general iTunes Fullscreen shortcut has no effect, nor does the green maximize/restore icon - in fact, that is hard to click anyway, since there's no mouse pointer shown in visualiser mode.

Anyone managed to get it running in Windowed mode?  I'd quite like to be able to see my mail unread badges while iTunes is running.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - I'd misread ^-CMD-F as SHIFT-CMD-F rather than CTRL-CMD-F